# Correct transformation of left-handed Weyl spinor

Tags: special-relativity, conventions, lorentz-symmetry, spinors

In the book "Matthew D. Schwartz, Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model", page 164, it says that a left-handed spinor transforms as

$$\psi_L \rightarrow e^{\frac{1}{2}(i\vec{\theta} - \vec{\beta})\vec{\sigma}} \psi_L.\tag{10.39}$$

In the book "Peskin, Schröder, An Introduction To Quantum Field Theory", page 44, it says that a lefthanded spinor transforms as

$$\psi_L \rightarrow e^{-\frac{1}{2}(i\vec{\theta} + \vec{\beta})\vec{\sigma}} \psi_L.\tag{3.37}$$

In the book "Anthony Duncan, The Conceptual Framework of Quantum Field Theory", page 76, it says that a spinor in the $(1/2,0)$ representation (I assume that is a lefthanded spinor) transforms as

$$\psi_L \rightarrow e^{-\frac{1}{2}(i\vec{\theta} - \vec{\beta})\vec{\sigma}} \psi_L.$$

All of them are different. Which transformation is correct?

If all of them are, why the different signs?

Comment: Unfortunate fact: Different authors have different conventions.

Comment: All signs here are solely a matter of convention. For example, switching between thinking of rotations/boosts as active, vs. passive, produces a sign flip. There is no problem as long as you are consistent in your conventions.

Comment: There must be a convention though for when a spinor is called lefthanded (regardless of the signs involved in the representations above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in some of the comments above, signs are a matter of convention, but they are not arbitrary ! Consistency is the key.

Since $e^{\pm i \frac{1}{2} \vec{\phi} \cdot \vec{\sigma} + \frac{1}{2} \vec{\beta} \cdot \vec{\sigma}}$ and $e^{\pm i \frac{1}{2} \vec{\phi} \cdot \vec{\sigma} - \frac{1}{2} \vec{\beta} \cdot \vec{\sigma}}$ (same sign for the rotation generators but a sign difference in the boost generators) are unitarily inequivalent, only one of them can be the transformation for a lefthanded spinor.

By consulting the sources I considered the most trustworthy (in the sense that they are quite explicit and comprehensive in the statement of their assumptions and conventions, and seem to use them consistently throughout) -
among them:

- Dreiner, H. K., Haber, H. E., & Martin, S. P. (2010). Two-component spinor techniques and Feynman rules for quantum field theory and supersymmetry. Physics Reports, 494(1-2), 1–196. doi:10.1016/j.physrep.2010.05.002 (http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.1594)
- Peskin Schröder, An Introduction to QFT
- Srednicki, Quantum Field Theory

I came to the conclusion that the following transformation is commonly agreed upon to be a **active rotation** (counterclockwise) with angle $\phi$ around the axis $\hat{\phi}$ and **active boost** with rapidity $\vec{\beta}$ for a lefthanded spinor:

$M_L = e^{-i \frac{1}{2} \vec{\phi} \cdot \vec{\sigma} - \frac{1}{2} \vec{\beta} \cdot \vec{\sigma}}$

---

In the case of "Anthony Duncan, The Conceptual Framework of Quantum Field Theory", he

- first talks about passive rotations and boosts (page 110, formula 5.9, 5.10)
- but then later seems to use a different conventions:

  ${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu = {\delta^\mu}_\nu + {\omega^\mu}_\nu$ for infinitesimal transformations (page 174, right after formula 7.19) and

  $\vec{\phi} = (\omega_{23},\omega_{31},\omega_{12})$, $\vec{\beta} = (\omega_{10},\omega_{20},\omega_{30})$ (page 175, right after formula 7.35)

  which together implie that he is using **passive rotations** but **active boosts**.

The latter is then consistent with

$M_L = e^{-i \frac{1}{2} \vec{\phi} \cdot \vec{\sigma} + \frac{1}{2} \vec{\beta} \cdot \vec{\sigma}}$ (page 176, formula 7.36)